# Python Watchdog get the name of the file that was just created?

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I have written a script that observes a directory for creation of new files. I set up a split function to split the event.src_path from the target directory that i was giving the observer. This allowed me to get the file_name successfully.

**See script below**

```
def on_created(event):
    source_path = event.src_path
    file_name = source_path.split(TargetDir,1)[1]
    print(f"{file_name} was just Created")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for dir in range(len(TargetDir)):
        event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()
        event_handler.on_created = on_created

        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path = TargetDir[0], recursive=True)

        observer.start()
```

However, now i am trying to feed in a list of Target directories and am looping through each one and calling the on_created() method. Now obviously the Target directory is no longer a global variable, and i need to try to pass each Dir in to the function. Im using watchdog, and don't think it's possible to add extra arguments to the on_created() function. If i'm wrong, please let me know how to do this? otherwise, is there no simpler way to just get the name of the file that was created, without passing in the target directory just for that reason? I can get the event.src, however this gives the full path, and then i wouldn't know where to split it, if it were scanning multiple directories.

Answer (score 0):

Well one simple way is to pass in a different function for each directory, for example :

```py
def create_callback(dir):
    def on_create(event):
        source_path = event.src_path
        file_name = source_path.split(dir, 1)[1]
        print(f"{file_name} was just Created")
    return on_create

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for dir in range(len(TargetDir)):
        event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()
        event_handler.on_created = create_callback(dir)

        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path=TargetDir[0], recursive=True)

        observer.start()
```

The `dir` variable is attached to the scope of the `on_create` function and can therefore be used from within the function.